# Passing values from razor form to model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I've got a .NET Core with Razor app, then there's a page. On it, there is a table and a form to show different (filter) data in that table (simple year-month and checkbox input). Form's method is set to GET. 
I noticed, that it is possible to pass form data into model in 2 different ways:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public bool ForUserOnly { get; set; }
```

or

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(DateTime date, bool forUserOnly)
```

Question is, which one should I use? What are the benefits of one and another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches are valid. It depends on what you need to achieve when submitting the `form`.

- Use `[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]` approach if need to access
  the properties outside of the handler method `OnGetAsync` e.g.
  displaying on the page
- Use `OnGetAsync` handler method approach when the properties are not
  needed outside of this handler method.

Regardless of which approach you use, the handler method will always be called that will allow you to add some custom logic e.g. custom validation or something.

If you have public properties defined like below, they will be bound either by using `QueryString` parameters or `RouteParameters`. When you submit the form using `GET` method, the parameters will be appended to the URL as query strings.

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public bool ForUserOnly { get; set; }
```

With the above code, the handler method will be parameterless

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    // do something here
}
```

Your submitted URL will become `https://youhost.com?date=value&forUserOnly=value`

If you are using the `OnGetAsync` handler method to bind the submitted model, then you don't need the `[BindProperty]` attribute, or even the public properties. As the submitted values will be passed to the handler method. It all depends on which approach you decide to use in the end.

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(DateTime date, bool forUserOnly)
{
}
```

I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, whole answer for me is in the first two bullets. It is worth mentioning, that when we use `[BindProperty]`, we need to include `asp-for` inside `<input>`.

Comment: Yes, right. I am glad I was able to help. If the answer was useful, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: However, you don't necessarily need to use the `asp-for`. It's a `TagHelper` that generates the `name` attribute. You can directly use it as well `<input type="text" name="FirstName" />`.